# How can I prevent concurrent builds in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We have several projects in CruiseControl and I noticed that often 2 or more projects are building at the same time.  This seems to be causing conflicts.  Often, a build fails and if I look at the reason, it's failing to access some file, and if I wait until the other build completes, I can just force-build the failed build and it will succeed.

How can I configure CC so that it won't run builds concurrently if they are going to conflict with each other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do all builds that depend on each other, in **one queue**.

The cruise control project configuration element has two attributes to control concurrency and order of build:

```
<project name="Project 1" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
```

With `queue` you can define in which queue the project shall be build, with `queuePriority` you can define the order of builds when several builds are requested.

So two projects that cannot be build in parallel have to be on the same queue, say `queue="Q1"`. When the second projects is dependend on the first one, the second project must have a higher priority than the first.

Comment: Does this prevent you from building a Project 1 without building Project 2?  Or will both always be built because they're in teh same queue?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Locking](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Queue_Configuration) feature to define queus that should not run at the same time.

This is available in version 1.4.3

A sample from the documentation:

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <queue name="Q1" lockqueues="Q2"/>
  <queue name="Q2" lockqueues="Q1"/>

  <project name="MyFirstProject" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
    ...
  </project>
  ...

  <project name="MySecondProject" queue="Q2" queuePriority="1">
    ...
  </project>
  ...
</cruisecontrol>
```